# Template recursion seems to not work in mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have a style as a `template:style1` which makes the text 50% smaller, and content `abc` in `template:content`.

I want to get the text from `template:content`, apply style from `template:style` to it, and display it.

so I use `{{style1|content}}`
but this is displaying the text

> content

rather than displaying the actual content `abc`.

The style is applied to the text `content`, however, the content `abc` is not fetched. This means that the evaluation is not happening, but it should according to [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

> {{style1| {{content}} }}

Answer (score 1):

To expand on why the other answer is correct, lets take a look at what you're doing.

`{{style|content}}` is calling the template `{{style}}` (the outer set of brackets), but then doesn't invoke `{{content}}`, because there are no brackets surrounding `content`. Rather `content` is a string you're feeding into the template. As the other answer points out if you want to invoke `content` as a parameter to `{{style}}` you need to separately invoke it, by using `{{content}}` inside of `{{style}}`, leading to the correct invocation of `{{style|{{content}}}}`